# Web2Lead form embedded in webpage need help

Tags: apex, visualforce, web2lead

I have created a web2lead form and have added in wordpress website page. Form work perfectly but on submitting the form thankyou page opens inside main page...

My website page (https://mywebsite.org.au/contact/):

```
<HTML>
 <head>
    //few styles here
</head>
<Body>
      //other things on website
      //My web2Lead Form starts here
```

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
      //form styles here
   </head>
<body id="page-top" class="index">


    <form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" class="contact-form">
    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D280000000001">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://friendsofrefugees.org.au/thank-you-for-contacting-for/">
    <input type=hidden name="00N2800000JCyxj" value="SOCIAL ENTERPRISES">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="city">City</label><input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="state">State/Province</label><input  id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

```
  /*My web2Lead Form ends here*/
<Body>
</HTML>
```

On Submit Thankyou page opens in same page (https://mywebsite.org.au/contact/) inside iframe tag

But I want to open thank you page as complete page not embedded in same page. How to open return URL outside Iframe.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have control of the `thank-you-for-contacting-for` page that users are redirected back to? If so, you could detect the iframe there and "bust" back out to the top window then.

Comment: Thanks for reply....I have access to thank you page but didn't quite got you answer...Also i have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Can you add JavaScript to the thank you page? Something like: `if (top != self) { top.location.replace(self.location.href); }`